# Breadcrumb Panels

Tags: user-interface, wizard, breadcrumbs, panels

I recently used a web application that employed a user interface pattern that I'd like to use.  I am not sure if there is a standard or tool sets that assist in the implementation.  It's a multi-path visual interface similar to a wizard.  A series of 'Breadcrumb Panels' that open in sequence and allow the user to navigate a transaction in a non-linear manner.

It resembles this:

http://i50.tinypic.com/vybdqg.jpg

Does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: I can't open your link, but what technology are you using? ASP.Net has a Wizard Control that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of a specific technology stack.  JQuery is where the client view would most likely be implemented.  It's very similar to a wizard but the steps open new panels to the right.  The user can easily navigate multiple paths to read and update related objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean like this:

JBREADCRUMB - AN AUTO COLLAPSING BREADCRUMB

http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html

But you need to consider what impact this will have for users on mobile devices and how google will see the navigation. Make sure you have alternatives that google can crawl, not just javascript based.

Comment: Yes, it's similar, but the 'crumbs' are actually fully interactive panels that can participate in transactions and navigation.